# Как получить текущего пользователя?

Tags: c#

Я знаю IP адрес компьютера  получаю без проблем его HostName, но как мне получить текущего пользователя на удаленном компьютере?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string IP = textBox1.Text;
            CompNameInfo.Text = Dns.GetHostEntry(IP).HostName;
            CurrentUser.Text = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent;

        }
```

`CurrentUser.Text = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent;` - здесь я получаю инфу , только о себе как мне передать туда IP или HostName и получить данные об удаленном компьютере?

Comment: А что значит - текущий пользователь на удалённом компьютере? В один промежуток времени на нём могут работать несколько пользователей. Что Windows, что Linux - многопользовательские многозадачные ОС. Уточните, что Вы имели в виду.

Comment: Я имею ввиду пользователя, который за логился на компьютере текущего, который в данный момент его использует.

Comment: Пользователя получить невозможно. Я например сейчас пишу этот текст со своего домашнего компьютера, находясь при этом на работе. Потому как зашел туда по RDP. т.е. дома у меня на компьютере никакой пользователь сейчас не работает. А я сейчас могу пойти в соседнюю комнату и по RDP подключить домой второй сеанс под другим пользователем. И у меня на домашнем компе будут работать одновременно два пользователя, при том что около компа никого нет. При этом из этого сеанса открыты putty на linux машину, один под root, другой под другим пользователем. в итоге на том linux уже 2 пользователя работают

Comment: Уточните, зачем вам пользователь, потому как в текущем виде ответ - никак.

Comment: CurrentUser.Text = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent; - Вот этим же способом он мне показывает, кто работает за моим компьютером , неужели нельзя это же сделать на удаленном компе?

Comment: Я хочу получить введя IP адрес текущего пользователя на удаленном компьютере, чтобы сопоставить в домене , кто на каком компьютере работает.

Comment: `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent` возвращает пользователя, под которым запущено ваше приложение. Посмотрите `runas` команду - она позволяет запустить приложение из под другого пользователя в той же пользовательской сессии. Вы хотите чего-то неправильного. Например, у меня на IP адресе находится роутер, на котором никакого Windows и пользователей Windows нет.

Comment: Ок. Explorer.exe под кем то запущен на удаленном компе, как мне узнать под кем?

Comment: >сопоставить в домене , кто на каком компьютере работает -- а работают под своими учетками или как? Вам нужен доступ к серверу ActiveDirectory тогда, дальше как то так например - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153133/search-active-directory-for-computer-names-using-user-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для получения сведений о удаленной машине внутри домена естественно нужны соответствующие привелегии.

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class CUdsObj
    {
        public string Domain {get; set; }

        public string User{get;set;}

        public string SID{get;set;}
    }

    public class CUserDomainSid
    {

        public CUserDomainSid(string scope = ".")
        {
            _scope = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", scope);
        }

        private readonly string _scope;

        public  CUdsObj GetUDS()
        {
            CUdsObj udsRetVal = new CUdsObj();

            string strQuery = "Select UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem";

            using (ManagementObjectSearcher mosItems = new ManagementObjectSearcher(_scope, strQuery))
            {
                foreach (ManagementBaseObject mbo in mosItems.Get())
                { 
                    string[] arr_strUserDom = mbo["UserName"].ToString().Split('\\');

                    udsRetVal.Domain = arr_strUserDom[0];
                    udsRetVal.User = arr_strUserDom[1];
                }
            }

            udsRetVal.SID =
                GetSid(udsRetVal.Domain, udsRetVal.User);

            return udsRetVal;
        }

        private string GetSid(string strDomain, string strUser)
        {
            string strRetValSid = "";

            #region QUERY_REGION
            string strQuery =
               string.Format(
                  "Select SID " +
                  "FROM Win32_UserAccount " +
                  "WHERE" +
                  " Domain='{0:G}'" +
                  " AND Name='{1:G}'",
                  strDomain, strUser);
            #endregion QUERY_REGION

            using (ManagementObjectSearcher mosItems = new ManagementObjectSearcher(_scope, strQuery))
            { 
                foreach (ManagementBaseObject mbo in mosItems.Get())
                { 
                    strRetValSid = mbo["SID"].ToString();
                }
            }

            return strRetValSid;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var r = new CUserDomainSid("192.168.56.1").GetUDS();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Есть еще вариант:

```
public class Win32_LogonSession
{

    public string AuthenticationPackage;
    public string LogonID;
    public LogonEventType LogonType;
    public string Name;
    public DateTime StartTime;

    public enum LogonEventType
    {
        System = 0,
        Interactive,
        Network,
        Batch,
        Service,
        Proxy,
        Unlock,
        NetworkClearText,
        NewCredentials,
        RemoteInteractive,
        CachedInteractive,
        CachedRemoteInteractive,
        CachedUnlock
    }

    public static List<Win32_LogonSession> GetList()
    {
        string query = "Select * From Win32_LogonSession";

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

        ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();

        List<Win32_LogonSession> list = new List<Win32_LogonSession>(results.Count);

        Dictionary<string, string> userTable = GetLoggedOnUsersTable();

        foreach (ManagementObject logonCurrent in results)
        {
            Win32_LogonSession entry = new Win32_LogonSession();

            entry.AuthenticationPackage = (string) logonCurrent["AuthenticationPackage"];
            entry.LogonID = (string) logonCurrent["LogonID"];
            entry.LogonType = (LogonEventType) Convert.ToInt32(logonCurrent["LogonType"]);
            entry.StartTime = ConvertFileTime((string) logonCurrent["StartTime"]);
            if (userTable.ContainsKey(entry.LogonID))
            {
                entry.Name = (string) userTable[entry.LogonID];
            }
            list.Add(entry);
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, string> GetLoggedOnUsersTable()
    {
        string query = "Select * From Win32_LoggedOnUser";

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

        ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();

        Dictionary<string, string> table = new Dictionary<string, string>(results.Count);

        foreach (ManagementObject currentObject in results)
        {
            string account = GetUser((string) currentObject["Antecedent"]);
            string session = GetLogonID((string) currentObject["Dependent"]);
            table.Add(session, account);
        }
        return table;
    }

    private static string GetLogonID(string propertyText)
    {
        string pattern = "LogonId=\"(?<id>\\d+)\"";
        Match matchID = Regex.Match(propertyText, pattern);
        if (matchID.Success)
        {
            return matchID.Groups["id"].Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private static string GetUser(string propertyText)
    {
        string pattern = "Domain=\"(?<domain>[A-Za-z\\d_-]+)\"|Name=\"(?<name>[A-Za-z\\d\\s_-]+)\"";
        string domain = "";
        string name = "";
        foreach (Match matchCurrent in Regex.Matches(propertyText, pattern))
        {
            string fullText = matchCurrent.Groups[0].Value;
            if (fullText.StartsWith("Domain"))
            {
                domain = matchCurrent.Groups["domain"].Value;
            }
            else
            {
                name = matchCurrent.Groups["name"].Value;
            }
        }
        if (domain.Length == 0)
        {
            return name;
        }
        else
        {
            return domain + "\\" + name;
        }
    }

    private static DateTime ConvertFileTime(string time)
    {
        if (time != null)
        {
            const string FILE_TIME_MASK = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
            time = time.Substring(0, time.IndexOf("."));
            return DateTime.ParseExact(time, FILE_TIME_MASK, null);
        }
        return DateTime.MinValue;
    }
}
```

Только нужно добавить определение скопа как показано в предыдущем примере.